# Can we see virtual DOM of React like we see Real DOM?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to view the virtual DOM like we view the Real DOM with Dev tools, if yes, please let me know how.

Comment: No, it's in memory.

Comment: theres a chrome extension that allows you to see the react hierachy

Comment: Install react dev tools

Comment: [React dev tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)